# iOS 9 Breaks Animations of UILabel

Tags: ios, uiview, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I migrated my code from Swift 1.2  to Swift 2.0

In Swift 1.2/ iOS8 , the animation just works. But in iOS 9, it does not animate it, the Label changes the position immediately as if the `layoutIfNeeded` was never called.

Here is how I animate my UILabel an UIButton. (I am using Autolayout, that's why I use layoutIfNeeded)

**USING UILABEL (DOES NOT WORK)**

```
titleLabelTopConstraint.constant = 88;

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.38, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.54, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.titleLabel.layoutIfNeeded();
        }, completion: nil);
```

**USING UIBUTTON (IT WORKS)**

```
buttonTopConstraint.constant = 88;

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.38, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.54, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.button.layoutIfNeeded();
        }, completion: nil);
```

However if I do the same on an UIButton, it works!.

Any thoughts? Why UILabel is not animatable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding:

```
self.titleLabel.setNeedsLayout();
```

before the animation block.

Comment: In general when you update a constraint on a view you should let the iOS layout system know that a constraint has changed by using the setNeedsLayout method. This is a performance optimization by apple so that they don't try to layout a view unnecessarily. As for why it works for the UIButton, I can't say for sure. Apple may be calling setNeedsLayout under the hood in the UIButton implementation.